# Update Magento2 version 2.4.3-p2 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have an issue with the upgrade of Magento from 2.4.3-p2 to 2.4.4.

Here my steps to reproduce:

1. composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update
2. composer update php-amqplib/php-amqplib

I have tried with option -W, but i get always this exception:

*Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4, found magento/product-community-edition[2.4.4] but the package is fixed to 2.4.3-p2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer 3.3.0, found friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer[v3.3.0] but the package is fixed to v2.18.7 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command......
Problem 3*

Could someone tell me, how can I start the upgrade with all dependencies?
Hint: This commande doesn't work "composer update -W"

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You can update the correct version on composer.json

Or just use the following command

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --update-with-all-dependencies
composer update php-amqplib/php-amqplib --with-all-dependencies
```